# How do I correctly set the routes on an ajax button_to?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have implemented an ajax-based button to add and remove a calendar event from a user's "wish list". The button behaves as a toggle-switch. If the event is already on their wish list, it will remove it; if it is not, then it will add it.

My issue is that the button works correctly when the page is first loaded, but after clicking it and replacing it with a new button_to via AJAX, it no longer works.

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895889/overriding-the-javascript-template-used-in-a-rails-remote-form-submission) but he has a slightly different architecture and I am not looking to completely refactor this just yet if I can avoid it. I have a separate model for the saved events. There are three models that come into play here: users, events, and saved_events. There is a many-to-many relationship between users and events which is represented as a saved_event. Here is the relevant code from the models.

user.rb:

```
  has_many :saved_events
  has_many :events, :through => :saved_events
```

event.rb:

```
  has_many :saved_events
  has_many :watchers, :class_name => "User", :through => :saved_events, :source => :user
```

saved_event.rb:

```
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
```

I have configured pretty standard routes.

routes.rb:

```
  resources :saved_events, :only => [:index,:create,:destroy]
  resources :users
  resources :events
```

I initially want to see this button an an event's page, so I added it to the event's show.html.erb. (I realize this isn't quite DRY yet - I am waiting until it works correctly to move it into a partial)

events/show.html.erb:

```
  <% if !@is_watched %>
    <%= button_to "Add to Wishlist", { :action => 'create', :controller => 'saved_events', :id => @event.id }, :remote => true %>
  <% else %>
    <%= button_to "Remove from Wishlist", saved_event_path(@event), :remote => true, :method => 'delete' %>
  <% end %>
```

events_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @is_watched = @event.watchers.exists?(current_user) if !current_user.nil?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @event }
      format.json { render :json => @event }
    end
  end
```

saved_events_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    logger.debug params.to_yaml

    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if !current_user.events.exists?(params[:id])
      current_user.events << @event
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logger.debug params.to_yaml

    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
    current_user.events.delete(@event)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My goal with the ajax was just to swap out the add form with the remove form (or vice-versa). So I have a create.js.erb and a destroy.js.erb which just use the same code from events/show.html.erb.

saved_events/create.js.erb:

```
$(".button_to").html("<%= escape_javascript button_to "Remove from Wishlist", saved_event_path(@event), :remote => true, :method => 'delete' %>");
```

saved_events/destroy.js.erb:

```
$(".button_to").html("<%= escape_javascript (button_to "Add to Wishlist", { :action => 'create', :controller => 'saved_events', :id => @event.id }, :remote => true) %>");
```

This is what I see in the log if the second button click is to "remove"

```
Started DELETE "/saved_events?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-02 11:56:58 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/saved_events"):
```

This is what I see in the log if the second button click is to "add"

```
Started POST "/saved_events/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-02 11:59:12 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/saved_events/1"):
```

On initial load of the page, the add button has "/saved_events?id=1" as its action, so I am confused as to why it would be "/saved_events/1" for the second button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was from my jquery. I needed to wrap the form in a div, and then call jquery.html() on that div rather than the form itself. I did some other refactoring in the controllers, which I won't post here for brevity, but here are my new js.erb files:

create.js.erb:

```
<% button_html = button_to( 'Remove from Wishlist', { :action => 'destroy', :id => @saved_event.id }, :remote => true, :method => 'delete' ) %>
$("#toggle_wishlist").html("<%= escape_javascript( button_html ) %>");
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#toggle_wishlist").html("<%= escape_javascript( button_to("Add to Wishlist", { :action => 'create', :controller => 'saved_events' }, :remote => true)) %>");
$("#toggle_wishlist .button_to").append("<%= escape_javascript( hidden_field_tag :event_id, @event.id ) %>");
```